# Bitcoind: Corruption: block checksum mismatch

Tags: debian, bitcoind

While indexing blocks I have error in debug.log:

`2016-11-14 15:14:52 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000038ad111e773453f172891263e1a7a2bca9b2017ac474c54fb0c  height=211020  log2_work=69.125688  tx=9563053  date=2012-12-05 20:04:23 progress=0.029749  cache=40.0MiB(40827tx)`

`2016-11-14 15:14:52 LoadExternalBlockFile: Processing out of order child 000000000000004f797d6a10f2b0fa1420b74c77dc335a37e3ab98efa76ebd2d of 000000000000038ad111e773453f172891263e1a7a2bca9b2017ac474c54fb0c`

`2016-11-14 15:14:52 LevelDB read failure: Corruption: block checksum mismatch`

`2016-11-14 15:14:52 Corruption: block checksum mismatch`

`2016-11-14 15:14:52 Error: Error reading from database, shutting down.`

`2016-11-14 15:14:52 Error reading from database: Database corrupted`

Answer (score 2):

I also encounter this problem. I remove the latest blk****.dat and rev****.dat file. It works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Install the newest version of bitcoind

I have `Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.11.3` instead `Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.13.1.0-g03422e5`